# Grails: Tag [remotelink] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-2.0

I'm trying to use g:remotelink tag in my project. When I try to render project home page I got the following error:

```
 Error mapping onto view [/index]: Error processing GroovyPageView: Tag [remotelink] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: Tag [remotelink] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g
->> 461 | runTask in /grails-app/views/index.gsp
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by GrailsTagException: Tag [remotelink] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: g
->>   8 | doCall  in /grails-app/views/index.gsp
```

What is going on here? I can use other grails tags in the same page without any problem!

Comment: Is it just the capitalization: `remoteLink`?

Comment: Yes this was the problem. Could you post it as answer?

Comment: I've done stuff like that more times than I care to remember...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like capitalization: `remoteLink`